# Performance impact on loading interrelated dropdowns with max of arounf 30,000 records

Tags: java, javascript, performance, jsp, drop-down-menu

Here is the scenario:

I have 4 drop downs in a JSP page in my Spring MVC application.
The dropdowns (Countries, States, divisions and villages) are related to each other as on selection of a particular country loads the state dropdown with state values and selection of a particular state loads the values in divisions dropdown and so on.
The maximum number of records in my application are:

- Countries: 75
- States: 1,000
- Divisions: 3,000
- Villages: 30,000

Data is present in 4 hashmaps like:

```
 - Map of String CountryId key with String Name as value
 - Map of String CountryId key with (Map of String StateId key with String StateName) as value
 - Map of String StateId key with (Map of String DivisionID key with String DivisionName) as value
 - Map of String DivisionId key with (Map of String VillageId key with String VillageName) as value
```

**Question:**

Currently I am loading all 4 hashmaps on JSP page and am displaying the values in dropdown based on the selection of previous dropdown:`

```
$("#country").on("change", function(e) {
    var stateMap = '${stateList}';
    var jsondata = $.parseJSON(stateMap );
    $.each(jsondata[$(this).val()], function (key, value) {
        $('#state').append($('<option></option>').val(key).html(value)).prop('disabled',false);
    });
});
```

Here, populating values in dropdown is handled in the javascript itself. **I did this to reduce the number of hits on server.**
 But given the large number of records in the hashmaps, is it the correct way to populate data in the dropdowns?
OR Should I do an AJAX call each time a value is selected in a dropdown to populate the values in subsequent dropdown.

Which one of these two approaches is more appropriate from the performance perspective.

Comment: You might want to consider using AJAX to download only the required portions of the lists. So when a Country is selected it downloads the list of states/counties for that country.

Comment: @Jaydee: Yes, i know that i have an option to populate only selective data based upon the value selected in dropdown. What I wish to know is that what is the better approach. To load data at once or to have multiple hits to server (Ajax) and load data there.

Comment: How do you define "better"? Downloading everything at once will mean you page will take longer to download initially but will be slightly more responsive. Using AJAX will mean the page will load faster initially but will have a lag after selecting each of the options. If you are running this on a 100mbit network, you may not notice the difference. Running it on a slow ADSL connection may mean that some people click for another page before the initial load completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here, populating values in dropdown is handled in the javascript itself. I did this to reduce the number of hits on server.But given the large number of records in the hashmaps, is it the correct way to populate data in the dropdowns?

It'd bet this is a good idea for

- Countries: 75

and maybe

- States: 1,000
- and maybe even Divisions: 3,000

but

- not for Villages: 30,000

> Should I do an AJAX call each time a value is selected in a dropdown to populate the values in subsequent dropdown.

I'd go for it. Each sublist is a static resource, there's nothing to compute and can be served pretty quickly. If you're lucky, the call takes something like 50-100 milliseconds, i.e., way below human perception.

You could also run a AJAX call to get the whole list. This would make you page load fast and the number of requests low. Finally, only measurement can tell you, what works best in you environment.

---

Note, that you don't have to make 4 requests, one for each entity type. You can e.g. put all 75 countries in your page itself and then load everything for the selected country.